# Why does my url spits out the two // at the end?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to React so bear with me here. I have this button here:

```
let showButton
if (schema.type === 'belongs_to') {
  showButton = (
    <Link to={['collections', 'locks', this.props.collectionName]}>
      <button>Visa</button>
    </Link>
  )
}
```

This button will redirect to this URL: `http://localhost:3000/#/collections/locks/` and there is nothing wrong with that, but when I'm adding this: `this.props.id` which is a legit prop, but the url I get is this: `http://localhost:3000/#/collections/locks//`. Notice the two **//** at the end.

#### My Question

Why does my url spits out the two **//** at the end? Is it because `this.props.id` is empty? As I said, I am very new to this. Thankful for all the support!

#### Code:

I just want to say that I'm maintaining this project, so all of the code is not written by me, therefor I might not know **every** little line.

However.. The `this.props.id` if from here:

```
class DeleteDocument extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { confirmed: false }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="DeleteDocument">
        <div className="box">
          <div className="title">
            Är du säker på att du vill ta bort dokumentet?
          </div>
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={this.state.confirmed}
              onChange={e =>
                this.setState({ confirmed: !this.state.confirmed })}
            />
            Ja, jag är säker
          </label>
          <div className="box" />
        </div>
        <div style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
          <button
            disabled={!this.state.confirmed}
            onClick={this.props.deleteDocument}
          >
            Ta bort
          </button>
          <div style={{ padding: '15px', borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc' }}>
            <Link to={'/collections/locks/${this.props.id}'}> HERE IT IS
              <button>Avbryt</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So I made a decision to use the same props because it's working here and the naming of it seemed to suit my use for it (don't know if this makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may be almost right in your assumption, `this.props.collectionName` may be empty, along with `this.props.id`.

For the following examples, imagine `_` to mean an empty string.

What I believe Link is doing here is joining the items in the array with a `/`. So if you have `['collections', 'locks', '_']` you will get `collections/locks/_`. Notice that there is a slash in the end, this is because there is an empty item in the array so Link does put a slash between that and the item before it. Not an issue since it is just one trailing slash.

Now, if you have `['collections', 'locks', '_', '_']` now there should be a slash between `locks` and `_`, and a slash between `_` and `_`. The result would look like this: `collections/locks/_/_`, now you have two trailing slashes, which I believe is not a valid move in URLs.

Take a look at the scope of your function there, are you sure you have the props that you are expecting?

Hope this explains the issue!

Comment: So when something is empty in Link it will be outputted as a `/`? Thanks for the explanation, it cleared up some thoughts!

Comment: Well, yes but that is not your proble, I beleive. Or not exactly. imagine you have `['test', 'one'].join('/')`. You get `test/one`. If you have `['test', 'one', '_'].join('/')` you get `test/one/_`. Now if you have `['test', 'one', '_', '_'].join('/')` you get `test/one/_/_` which is our issue. It seems to be that when you sent an array to `Link to=(here)` it runs `.join('/')` on it.

Answer (score 0):

change `{'/collections/locks/${this.props.id}'}` to `{'/collections/locks/'+ this.props.id}`

Comment: `this.props.id` seems to be undefined

Comment: passing data through the Link component might be tricky. You
can include additional
information through the
state property of the
location.

Comment: Do you have a link to get information about stuff like that (hehe)?

Comment: @MartinNordström you can check the Link docs https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/API.md#link or http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Answer (score -2):

Seems you id - is empty string. So you need to share code where you use this.props.id

Comment: change {'/collections/locks/${this.props.id}'} to {'/collections/locks/'+ this.props.id}

Comment: this.props.id seems to be undefined – Martin Nordström